# Sequence and series sum doubt

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $V_r$ denote the sum of first $r $terms of an arithmetic progression whose first term is $r$ and the common difference is $(2r-1) $ then $$V_{ r+1} -V_r - 2$$ is always what type of number?

My take:
Since $$V_{ r+1} -V_r =T_{  r+1} $$ 
And we can compute the $ r+1^{th     }    $term using the property of AP hence the $ r+1^{th     }    $term  is $$T_{  r+1} =2r^2$$

Now subtracting by 2 gives me $    2(r^2 - 1)  $ which is an even number.  But my book answer says it must be a composite number (it can also include odd numbers).  How do I figure out the right solution?

Comment: Seems okay.. It cannot take odd values

Comment: @mfl yes u  are right.